How can I get correct indentation in neovim for Rails?
Using Neovim does not seem to give correct method arguments alignment (i.e. conformant with the Ruby and Rails style guides).
Specifically, this example:
      redirect_to @foo,
        notice: I18n.t('template.model_created', model: Foo.new.model_name.human)


is indented as above by either the default Neovim ruby indenting or the vim-ruby indenting.  However, according to the Ruby style guide here, the indentation should be like this:
      redirect_to @foo,
                  notice: I18n.t('template.model_created', model: Foo.new.model_name.human)


I can get the right indenting by using parentheses after the redirect_to(...) call:
      redirect_to(@foo,
                  notice: I18n.t('template.model_created', model: Foo.new.model_name.human))


but according to the Ruby style guide on dsl method calls, one should not use parentheses after dsl methods like redirect_to.
I have tried both the default indenting with neovim and vim-ruby, but both behave as above.  I have also looked into TreeSitter and vim-rails, but neither seems to do anything for indentation.
Is there a way to make this work without writing my own luascript?  It seems like anyone using Neovim with Rails would have hit this same problem, so I am probably missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Edit:
Environment is:
Using NVIM v0.10.0
Os X 14.5
Indenting with vim-ruby
  :verbose set indentexpr?
  indentexpr=GetRubyIndent(v:lnum)
    Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/vim-ruby/indent/ruby.vim

Indenting with default nvim indent for ruby:
:verbose set indentexpr?
indentexpr=GetRubyIndent(v:lnum)
    Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/indent/ruby.vim

Both indent the code exactly the same.

Thanks @smathy.  It does the second indent for me only if I put an open parentheses after redirect_to().
